# How do I use a variable outside the for loop in batch file?

Tags: batch-file

I have a list "A.txt" that has a list of remote servers.

I need to do a net time in all of them and then echo the result with the remote server name.
Example : "server 10/10/2018 19:00"

This is my code :

```
FOR /f %%G IN (D:\A.txt) DO (
    net time \\%%G
)>> B.txt 

FOR  /f "tokens=5,7,8" %%H IN (D:\B.txt) DO (echo %%H %%I %%J >> nettime.csv)

The result of this is : 

"\\Server1 10/10/2018 10:40:09 

 com   

 \\Server2 10/10/2018 10:40:09 

 com
```

It reads the token of the "command successful" line(I have Portuguese language on OS)

Is there a way to put the %%G in the echo? or can I hide the "command successful"?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pipe the output of the `NET` command to the `FIND` command to search for the string `Current` or whatever it is in your language.  You can capture all of this with a `FOR /F` command.

```
@ECHO off
FOR /f "delims=" %%G IN (D:\A.txt) DO (
    FOR  /f "tokens=5,7,8" %%H IN ('net time \\%%G ^| find "Current"') DO echo %%H %%I %%J
)>> nettime.csv
```